# How to autosubmit on select form but the option not back to default again?

Tags: php, html

Hello sorry for bad title, i dont know what to say. but i got problem when i want to implement autosubmit select but when the apge rendering, the option is back to normal again. not change to what i choose. for eg. in option i choose Cora but after i choose  it, the page render for a sec. and the option back to Default as All Races not Cora. but the pages already change to cora. because i have a validation on it. i dont know how to make we can choose the optioon and the option the display what i choose not back to normal again ? because i can choose default as All races for all race, and cora just cora that i filter in sql. look picture below

my php code

```
$out .= '<form method="POST" >';
    $out .= '   <table class="table table-bordered table-condensed"><tbody>';
    $out .- '       <tr>';
    $out .= '           <td class="info" width="5%"><b>Race</b></td>';
    $out .= '           <td>';
    $out .= '               <select class="form-control" name="race_select" onChange="this.form.submit()" >';
    $out .= '                   <option>All Races</option>';
    $out .= '                   <option>Accretia</option>';
    $out .= '                   <option>Bellato</option>';
    $out .= '                   <option>Cora</option>';
    $out .= '               </select>';
    $out .= '           </td>';
    $out .= '       </tr>';
    $out .= '   </tbody></table>';
    $out .= '</form>';
    $out .= '<br>';
```

my picture
[image]

look i choose for example in option Bellato and option not change to bellato but the page display only bellato.. how to make option change to what i choose? because i can choose all races too ? for first time display that will show all races but we can chosoe all races after we choose another option ..

Comment: use `selected` attribute to keep it selected.

Comment: but it always selected just one option